# Replacing/Stripping certain text from data in pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, pandas, strip

I've got an issue with Pandas not replacing certain bits of text correctly...

```
# Create blank column
csvdata["CTemp"] = ""
# Create a copy of the data in "CDPure"
dcol = csvdata.CDPure
# Fill "CTemp" with the data from "CDPure" and replace and/or remove certain parts
csvdata['CTemp'] = dcol.str.replace(" (AMI)", "").replace(" N/A", "Non")
```

But yet when i print it hasn't replaced any as seen below by running `print csvdata[-50:].head(50)`

```
         Pole     KI   DE    Score   STAT  CTemp
4429      NaN      NaN  NaN      42    NaN  Data N/A 
4430      NaN      NaN  NaN   23.43    NaN  Data (AMI)
4431      NaN      NaN  NaN    7.05    NaN  Data (AMI)
4432      NaN      NaN  NaN    9.78    NaN  Data 
4433      NaN      NaN  NaN  169.68    NaN  Data (AMI)
4434      NaN      NaN  NaN   26.29    NaN  Data N/A
4435      NaN      NaN  NaN   83.11    NaN  Data  N/A
```

NOTE: The CSV is rather big so I have to use `pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', 250)` to be able to print the above.

Anyone know how I can make it replace those parts correctly in pandas?

#### EDIT, I've tried `.str.replace("", "")` and tried just `.replace("", "")`

Example CSV:

```
No,CDPure,Blank
1,Data Test,
2,Test N/A,
3,Data N/A,
4,Test Data,
5,Bla,
5,Stack,
6,Over (AMI),
7,Flow (AMI),
8,Test (AMI),
9,Data,
10,Ryflex (AMI),
```

Example Code:

```
# Import pandas
import pandas

# Open csv (I have to keep it all as dtype object otherwise I can't do the rest of my script)
csvdata = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', dtype=object)

# Create blank column
csvdata["CTemp"] = ""
# Create a copy of the data in "CDPure"
dcol = csvdata.CDPure
# Fill "CTemp" with the data from "CDPure" and replace and/or remove certain parts
csvdata['CTemp'] = dcol.str.replace(" (AMI)", "").str.replace(" N/A", " Non")

# Print
print csvdata.head(11)
```

Output:

```
    No        CDPure Blank         CTemp
0    1     Data Test   NaN     Data Test
1    2      Test N/A   NaN      Test Non
2    3      Data N/A   NaN      Data Non
3    4     Test Data   NaN     Test Data
4    5           Bla   NaN           Bla
5    5         Stack   NaN         Stack
6    6    Over (AMI)   NaN    Over (AMI)
7    7    Flow (AMI)   NaN    Flow (AMI)
8    8    Test (AMI)   NaN    Test (AMI)
9    9          Data   NaN          Data
10  10  Ryflex (AMI)   NaN  Ryflex (AMI)
```

Comment: One thing is you forgot to use `str` again for the second replace.  You need `dcol.str.replace(" (AMI)", "").str.replace(" N/A", "Non")`.  Not sure if that is the whole problem though.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, I just edited my post. I've tried both but neither are working.

Comment: Can you provide a complete, trimmed-down example with sample data illustrating the problem?

Comment: @BrenBarn, Edited and added an example csv, example code and example output. It shows that the only one that works is the `N/A` one but the `(AMI)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.replace` interprets its argument as a regular expression, so you need to escape the parentheses using `dcol.str.replace(r" \(AMI\)", "").str.replace(" N/A", "Non")`.

This does not appear to be adequately documented; [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) mention that `split` and `replace` "take regular expressions, too", but doesn't make it clear that they always interpret their argument as a regular expression.

Comment: I found a work around too, by doing `.str.replace(u"(", "").str.replace(u")", "")` and then adding a second replace to remove/change the text part.